# Reason of doing relational decomposition

Tags: mysql, database, decomposition

I was recently giving a job interview in which the interviewer asked me why do we decompose a database relation into several smaller tables using functional dependency? I answered that decomposition helps in eliminating some of the bad designs such as redundancy, inconsistency and upadation and insertion anomaly. The interviewer didn't seem to be convinced with my answer.

I have question that shouldn't it be difficult to manage two tables instead of one, when we decompose it. It should be easy to query just one table instead of two. I didn't find any detailed explanation for the actual reason behind decomposition?

Could anyone help me in getting the answer?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I agree with your answer the main reason behind the Normalization, is to reduce redundancy and insertion deletion anomalies. Briefly to have high quality and easily-maintainable data base system.

Comment: Perhaps it was your omission of the word 'normalisation', but under the circumstances your answer seems like a good one to me. I'd have given you the job.